# Content Security Policy works on some App Services but not others

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a content security policy added to the web.config of my application. This application is deployed to multiple Azure App Services. The web.configs are identical.

However, it only shows the CSPs in the Dev app services, and one of the QA app services. We have scoured logs, verified configs, went through Azure settings but can’t locate anything that would block the content security policies from displaying in browser headers on only certain app services and not others. For example:

Dev CMS App Service - devcm.azurewebsites.net address displays the CSPs in browser headers

Dev CDS App Service - devcd.azurewebsites.net and custom domain addresses displays the CSPs in browser headers

QA CMS App Service - qacm.azurewebsites.net address DOES NOT display the CSPs in browser headers

QA CDS App Service - qacd.azurewebsites.net address displays the CSPs in browser headers… but the custom domains DO NOT display the CSPs in the browser headers

The last case is the most confusing as the QA CDS has only 1 web.config that both the qacd.azurewebsites.net and custom domains use yet only the qacd.azurewbites.net shows the CSPs in the browser header.

Is there a setting somewhere in Azure (App Service, App Service Plan, Private Endpoints, etc.) that could affect the display of headers?

Answer (score 0):

We have found the issue. On the environments in question, it was referencing pipelines that did not exist in that environment, so it would not load or provide an incomplete load as our patching file to patch the desired pipeline for CSP was only partially matched. Ensuring that we patched after pipelines that exist in each environment resolved the issue.